# Manage detached entity with Entity Framework

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

My application reads an XML file and create a `PatientDto` that I use in the method `CreatePatient(PatientDto patient)`

This method **maps** the `PatientDto` to a `Patient` and stores it with Entity Framework. By mapping, I mean create a new `Patient` with the values of `PatientDto`

This patient is written as follow:

```
public class PatientDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DietDto> Diets { get; set; }
}

internal class Patient
{ 
    public Patient(PatientDto dto)
    {
        this.Name = dto.Name;
        this.Diets = this.BuildDiets(dto.Diets);
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Diet> Diets { get; set; }
}
```

A `Diet` has a list of `Week` that has a list of `Day` that has a list of `Meal` that has a list of `Ingredient`.

When I create a new patient, all the objects of the graph are new (That's they should be stored in the database) **but** the ingredients. The ingredients already exist in the database.

Because of the mapping, all the ingredients are different instances (even if they have the same business meaning. That's two ingredients with the same ID have different instances).

And when I execute my code, I've got an exception:

```
A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = Ingredients,Constraint name = PK_dbo.Ingredients ]
```

The quick fix I've found is this one:

```
foreach (var diet in patient.Diets)
    foreach (var week in diet.Weeks)
        foreach (var day in week.Days)
            foreach (var recipe in day.Meals)
                for (int i = 0; i < recipe.Recipe.Ingredients.Count; i++)
                {
                    recipe.Recipe.Ingredients[i] = (from igt in this.Context.Ingredients
                                                    where igt.Id == recipe.Recipe.Ingredients[i].Id
                                                    select igt).Single();
                }
```

But, it's not really readable and a loop in a loop in a loop, in a ... is not what I call optimised code.

Is there another way to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the actual Ingredient object retreived from the context for EF to update the database correctly. And it looks as you need to do some looping to do that for all your entites in the object graph. What you should do is reduce the amount of database access in this case and perhaps this code will help you in that direction.

```
var ingredientIds = recipe.Recipe.Ingredients.Select(ingredient => ingredient.Id).ToList();
List<Ingredients> dbIngredients = this.Context.Ingredients.Where(ingredient => ingredientIds.Contains(ingredient.Id)).ToList();
recipe.Recipe.Ingredients = dbIngredients;
```

And anyone struggling with updating object graphs with EF and related entities should also check out [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff)